# Vanity URL Error: Object Not found

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

For some reason I am getting a vanity URL error, and no other posts have sufficiently answered the question. What's wrong with the PHP code?

```
if (isset($_GET['username']) === true && empty($_GET['username']) === false) {
$username = $_GET['username'];
echo $username;
}
```

and my `.htaccess` file is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lr/profile.php?username=$1
```

If I go to `/projects/lr/profile.php?username=harrison7042`, it works but if I go to `/projects/lr/harrison7042` it doesn't work and just returns: `Object not found!`.

If I change this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lr/profile.php?username=$1
```

To this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ projects/lr/profile.php?username=$1
```

The server returns an `Internal Server Error`. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, or what. I followed along perfectly with the tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrc4p-J_x9s&list=ECE134D877783367C7).

Thanks, 
Harrison

Comment: `Object not found!` is coming from your script.  There's no way we can help you with that, as you haven't shown the code behind it.  Do a `print_r($_GET)` and show us that instead.  Otherwise, we can only help you generally with the rewrite rules.

Comment: @Brad I can't get the print_r($_GET) on the projects/lr/harrison7042 or whatever username but on projects/lr/profile.php?username=harrison7042 I get "Array ( [username] => harrison7042 )".

Comment: @Brad What could go wrong if I followed the video.

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess change:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /lr/profile.php?username=$1
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1
```